# negatively charged albumin as major carrier of acidic/negative charged drugs in blood

Tags: proteins, pharmacology, pharmacokinetics

I reading that orsomucoid (alpha-1-acid glycoprotein) is the major carrier of positively charged (basic) drugs in the blood, while **albumin carries negatively charged (acidic) and drugs with neutral charge**.

On the other hand I've read that albumin is excluded by the basement membrane in the glomeruli, and in general by negatively charged glycosaminoglycans in the interstitial space, because **albumin is negatively charged**.

I did a quick search online and I couldn't **find the information explaining this contradiction**. Does anyone have an explaination?

Comment: Running the [sequence](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P02768) for human albumin through expasy [protparam](http://web.expasy.org/protparam/) confirms albumin is negative at neutral pH. This [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25253445) provides experimental evidence that albumin is negative because it reverses the charge on positively charged DNA-peptide particles. However, simply because albumin is overall negatively charged doesn't mean it has a uniform charge. There are probably pockets with positively charged or hydrophobic character.